# JLabel Not Showing up when i run the program, but shows in my GUI builder in NetBeans

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, netbeans, jlabel

I am using Java GUI builder in NetBeans(drag and drop), and I added JLabels, Text Fields and Buttons in a container. However, only Text Fields and Buttons are showing up and not JLabels.

```
/*
 * Click nbfs://nbhost/SystemFileSystem/Templates/Licenses/license-default.txt to change this license
 * Click nbfs://nbhost/SystemFileSystem/Templates/GUIForms/JPanel.java to edit this template
 */
package View;

/**
 *
 * @author Yash
 */
public class ModifyTransactionPanel extends javax.swing.JPanel {

    private MainFrame mainFrame;
    /**
     * Creates new form HomePanel
     */
    public ModifyTransactionPanel(MainFrame mainFrame) {
        this.mainFrame = mainFrame;
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        menuPanel = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        menuItems = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        backButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
        logoutButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
        exitButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
        expenseTrackerLogoContainer = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        expenseTrackerLogo = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        modifyTransactionPanelContainer = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        addIncomeTitleLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        searchBar = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        searchButton = new java.awt.Button();
        searchTransactionIDButton = new java.awt.Label();
        searchResultContainer = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        resultTransactionID = new java.awt.Label();
        resultTransactionTypeLabel = new java.awt.Label();
        resultTransactionIDLabel = new java.awt.Label();
        resultNameLabel = new java.awt.Label();
        resultName = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        resultDateLabel = new java.awt.Label();
        resultDate = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        resultCategoryLabel = new java.awt.Label();
        resultCategory = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        resultAmountLabel = new java.awt.Label();
        resultAmount = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        updateTransactionButton = new java.awt.Button();
        addIncomeButton1 = new java.awt.Button();

        setLayout(new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteLayout());

        menuPanel.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0));
        menuPanel.setLayout(new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteLayout());

        menuItems.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0));
        menuItems.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
        menuItems.setLayout(new java.awt.GridLayout(3, 0));

        backButton.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0));
        backButton.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial", 0, 18)); // NOI18N
        backButton.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        backButton.setText("Back");
        backButton.setBorder(null);
        backButton.setBorderPainted(false);
        backButton.setCursor(new java.awt.Cursor(java.awt.Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
        menuItems.add(backButton);

        logoutButton.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0));
        logoutButton.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial", 0, 18)); // NOI18N
        logoutButton.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        logoutButton.setText("Logout");
        logoutButton.setBorder(null);
        logoutButton.setBorderPainted(false);
        logoutButton.setCursor(new java.awt.Cursor(java.awt.Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
        menuItems.add(logoutButton);

        exitButton.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0));
        exitButton.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial", 0, 18)); // NOI18N
        exitButton.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        exitButton.setText("Exit");
        exitButton.setBorder(null);
        exitButton.setBorderPainted(false);
        exitButton.setCursor(new java.awt.Cursor(java.awt.Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
        exitButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                exitButtonActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        menuItems.add(exitButton);

        menuPanel.add(menuItems, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(0, 270, 370, 730));

        expenseTrackerLogo.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/expenseTrackerLogo.jpg"))); // NOI18N
        expenseTrackerLogo.setOpaque(true);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout expenseTrackerLogoContainerLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(expenseTrackerLogoContainer);
        expenseTrackerLogoContainer.setLayout(expenseTrackerLogoContainerLayout);
        expenseTrackerLogoContainerLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
            expenseTrackerLogoContainerLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(expenseTrackerLogo, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        expenseTrackerLogoContainerLayout.setVerticalGroup(
            expenseTrackerLogoContainerLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(expenseTrackerLogo, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        menuPanel.add(expenseTrackerLogoContainer, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(0, 0, 370, 270));

        add(menuPanel, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(0, 0, 370, 1000));

        modifyTransactionPanelContainer.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        modifyTransactionPanelContainer.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0));

        addIncomeTitleLabel.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        addIncomeTitleLabel.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial", 1, 36)); // NOI18N
        addIncomeTitleLabel.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0));
        addIncomeTitleLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
        addIncomeTitleLabel.setText("ModifyTransaction");

        searchBar.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        searchBar.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial", 0, 14)); // NOI18N

        searchButton.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0));
        searchButton.setCursor(new java.awt.Cursor(java.awt.Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
        searchButton.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial", 0, 18)); // NOI18N
        searchButton.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        searchButton.setLabel("Search");
        searchButton.setName(""); // NOI18N
        searchButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                searchButtonActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        searchTransactionIDButton.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial", 0, 20)); // NOI18N
        searchTransactionIDButton.setText("Search Transaction ID");

        searchResultContainer.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        searchResultContainer.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));

        resultTransactionID.setAlignment(java.awt.Label.CENTER);
        resultTransactionID.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial", 1, 20)); // NOI18N
        resultTransactionID.setText("INC000001");

        resultTransactionTypeLabel.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial", 1, 20)); // NOI18N
        resultTransactionTypeLabel.setText("(Income)");

        resultTransactionIDLabel.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial", 0, 20)); // NOI18N
        resultTransactionIDLabel.setText("Transaction ID:");

        resultNameLabel.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial", 0, 20)); // NOI18N
        resultNameLabel.setText("Income Name");

        resultName.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        resultName.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial", 0, 14)); // NOI18N

        resultDateLabel.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial", 0, 20)); // NOI18N
        resultDateLabel.setText("Date (in dd/mm/yyyy format)");

        resultDate.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        resultDate.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial", 0, 14)); // NOI18N

        resultCategoryLabel.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial", 0, 20)); // NOI18N
        resultCategoryLabel.setText("Category");

        resultCategory.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        resultCategory.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial", 0, 14)); // NOI18N

        resultAmountLabel.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial", 0, 20)); // NOI18N
        resultAmountLabel.setText("Amount");

        resultAmount.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        resultAmount.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial", 0, 14)); // NOI18N

        updateTransactionButton.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0));
        updateTransactionButton.setCursor(new java.awt.Cursor(java.awt.Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
        updateTransactionButton.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial", 0, 18)); // NOI18N
        updateTransactionButton.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        updateTransactionButton.setLabel("Update");
        updateTransactionButton.setName(""); // NOI18N
        updateTransactionButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                updateTransactionButtonActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        addIncomeButton1.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0));
        addIncomeButton1.setCursor(new java.awt.Cursor(java.awt.Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
        addIncomeButton1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial", 0, 18)); // NOI18N
        addIncomeButton1.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        addIncomeButton1.setLabel("Delete");
        addIncomeButton1.setName(""); // NOI18N
        addIncomeButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                addIncomeButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout searchResultContainerLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(searchResultContainer);
        searchResultContainer.setLayout(searchResultContainerLayout);
        searchResultContainerLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
            searchResultContainerLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, searchResultContainerLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(48, 48, 48)
                .addComponent(updateTransactionButton, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 157, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 94, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addGroup(searchResultContainerLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(addIncomeButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 157, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(resultTransactionTypeLabel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 145, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(43, 43, 43))
            .addGroup(searchResultContainerLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(searchResultContainerLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(46, 46, 46)
                    .addGroup(searchResultContainerLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                        .addGroup(searchResultContainerLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addComponent(resultTransactionIDLabel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                            .addComponent(resultTransactionID, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addComponent(resultAmount, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 406, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(resultAmountLabel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 406, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(resultCategory, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 406, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(resultCategoryLabel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 406, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(resultDate, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 406, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(resultDateLabel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 406, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(resultName, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 406, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(resultNameLabel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 406, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                    .addContainerGap(47, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
        );
        searchResultContainerLayout.setVerticalGroup(
            searchResultContainerLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, searchResultContainerLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(20, 20, 20)
                .addComponent(resultTransactionTypeLabel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addGap(441, 441, 441)
                .addGroup(searchResultContainerLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(updateTransactionButton, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 42, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(addIncomeButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 42, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(30, 30, 30))
            .addGroup(searchResultContainerLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(searchResultContainerLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(22, 22, 22)
                    .addGroup(searchResultContainerLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addComponent(resultTransactionIDLabel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(resultTransactionID, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                    .addGap(28, 28, 28)
                    .addComponent(resultNameLabel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 27, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addComponent(resultName, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 35, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                    .addComponent(resultDateLabel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 27, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addComponent(resultDate, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 36, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addGap(24, 24, 24)
                    .addComponent(resultCategoryLabel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 27, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addComponent(resultCategory, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 36, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addGap(23, 23, 23)
                    .addComponent(resultAmountLabel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 35, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addComponent(resultAmount, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 34, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addGap(121, 121, 121)))
        );

        javax.swing.GroupLayout modifyTransactionPanelContainerLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(modifyTransactionPanelContainer);
        modifyTransactionPanelContainer.setLayout(modifyTransactionPanelContainerLayout);
        modifyTransactionPanelContainerLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
            modifyTransactionPanelContainerLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(modifyTransactionPanelContainerLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(374, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addGroup(modifyTransactionPanelContainerLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, modifyTransactionPanelContainerLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGroup(modifyTransactionPanelContainerLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addComponent(searchTransactionIDButton, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, modifyTransactionPanelContainerLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addComponent(searchBar, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 250, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addGap(24, 24, 24)
                                .addComponent(searchButton, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 132, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                        .addGap(350, 350, 350))
                    .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, modifyTransactionPanelContainerLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(addIncomeTitleLabel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 355, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addGap(374, 374, 374))))
            .addGroup(modifyTransactionPanelContainerLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, modifyTransactionPanelContainerLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addContainerGap(327, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(searchResultContainer, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addContainerGap(304, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
        );
        modifyTransactionPanelContainerLayout.setVerticalGroup(
            modifyTransactionPanelContainerLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(modifyTransactionPanelContainerLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(90, 90, 90)
                .addComponent(addIncomeTitleLabel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 87, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(37, 37, 37)
                .addComponent(searchTransactionIDButton, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(modifyTransactionPanelContainerLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(searchBar, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 35, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(searchButton, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                .addGap(713, 713, 713))
            .addGroup(modifyTransactionPanelContainerLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, modifyTransactionPanelContainerLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addContainerGap(309, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(searchResultContainer, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addContainerGap(130, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
        );

        add(modifyTransactionPanelContainer, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(370, 0, 1130, 1000));
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void exitButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        System.exit(0);
    }                                          

    private void updateTransactionButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                        
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        mainFrame.showTransactionPanel();
    }                                                       

    private void searchButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                            

    private void addIncomeButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                 
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                                


    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private java.awt.Button addIncomeButton1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel addIncomeTitleLabel;
    private javax.swing.JButton backButton;
    private javax.swing.JButton exitButton;
    private javax.swing.JLabel expenseTrackerLogo;
    private javax.swing.JPanel expenseTrackerLogoContainer;
    private javax.swing.JButton logoutButton;
    private javax.swing.JPanel menuItems;
    private javax.swing.JPanel menuPanel;
    private javax.swing.JPanel modifyTransactionPanelContainer;
    private javax.swing.JTextField resultAmount;
    private java.awt.Label resultAmountLabel;
    private javax.swing.JTextField resultCategory;
    private java.awt.Label resultCategoryLabel;
    private javax.swing.JTextField resultDate;
    private java.awt.Label resultDateLabel;
    private javax.swing.JTextField resultName;
    private java.awt.Label resultNameLabel;
    private java.awt.Label resultTransactionID;
    private java.awt.Label resultTransactionIDLabel;
    private java.awt.Label resultTransactionTypeLabel;
    private javax.swing.JTextField searchBar;
    private java.awt.Button searchButton;
    private javax.swing.JPanel searchResultContainer;
    private java.awt.Label searchTransactionIDButton;
    private java.awt.Button updateTransactionButton;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

[Here is the design:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0oJQA.png)

[Here is what it looks like when i run it:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cxjyW.png)

I tried checking if the visitiblity for everything is true, and it was true

Comment: You're mixing heavy-weight AWT components, such as `java.awt.Label`, with Swing GUI's. Don't do this. Use only `javax.swing.JLabel`s, not `java.awt.Label`s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not just adding JLabels; you're also adding `java.awt.Label` components:

```
private java.awt.Label resultAmountLabel;
```

Don't do this. Don't mix heavy-weight AWT components, such as Labels, with light weight Swing GUI's. Instead, every `java.awt.Label` should be declared and initialized as a `javax.swing.JLabel`.

The same is true for Button. Instead of,

```
searchButton = new java.awt.Button();
```

and

```
private java.awt.Button searchButton;
```

You should do:

```
searchButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
```

and

```
private javax.swing.JButton searchButton;
```

Note that it is OK to use non-component `java.awt` classes, such as those for Font, Color, layout managers, and such.
This is likely happening because you are choosing the wrong components with your NetBeans GUI builder, and will have to be more careful.

Or even better, learn to create GUI's without use of a GUI builder.